# Best API to display Google Analytics data in my Admin panel with Codeigniter PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

There are a lot of results on Google for this, but most of them are old more than an year.

I simply want to display some nice charts with jQuery in my admin with visits per day, most visited pages with number of visits, etc. I don't want to store the data for the visits in my database, the one at Google Analytics is perfect :)

Comment: Not a constructive question.  In its current form, solicits debate/discussion, and is thus a not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Sorry if It is going that way, my intentions were someone to point some good API or way to pull their data.

Comment: http://www.embeddedanalytics.com   Not a php solution.  In fact doesn't even require programming of any sorts.  But a simple/secure way to build an admin dashboard into your site.  (disclosure - I workd with the company).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [gapi-google-analytics-php-interface](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/). The code has many examples which should be useful for you.

The code has not been updated in a while, so you should [read this bug](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/issues/detail?id=75&q=https://developers.google.com/) about what URLs to update inside the source code.

Comment: I will try to implement, just tell me, is it fast enough to use it on the front end too? I want to display 10 Most popular news for the past 24 hours, 7 days, 30 days. Can I get that statistic from there or it would be too slow?

Comment: It depends on how you have set up your analytics, but if everything is tagged correctly, and you make sure that you cache your credentials -- it should be fine :)

Comment: And is there some official API from Google analytics? Not some third party library, but something simple and official from Google that will probably work fast enough?

Comment: That library does use the official API for Google Analytics :) As for a PHP library that is written by Google, I don't believe there is, but I could be wrong! I have always used GAPI and it has done me fine every time :)

Comment: Ok, these days I will test it and see how it works on real web site with thousands of visitors :)